# JsonResult returning "undefined"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, jsonresult

Hello in an MVC application I have the following function in the `AccountController.cs`:

```
public JsonResult IsAvailableUN(string Username)
{
    return Json(!Conn.Accounts.Any(Accounts => Accounts.Username == Username), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

where `Conn` is my connection, `Accounts` is the table's and the models's name and `Username` is a string from the text box and the table's column name.

In the `Accounts` model I have the following configuration above the public string `Username`:

```
[Remote("IsAvailableUN", "Account", ErrorMessage = "This username is already taken!")]
```

and in my View I have included the required `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js`

This should trigger my `Username` text box to give an error by typing an existing username and hitting `tab` afterwords, however, the browser's console returns:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
at HTMLFormElement.l (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:5)
at Object.e [as errorPlacement] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at c.validator.showLabel (jquery.validate.min.js:36)
at c.validator.defaultShowErrors (jquery.validate.min.js:34)
at c.validator.showErrors (jquery.validate.min.js:28)
at Object.success (jquery.validate.min.js:46)
at i (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
```

and my returned json contains only 1 word: `undefined`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: can u post the json u receive? cos if the browser is not lying u r not receiving a json back & browsers hardly lie

Comment: All I receive is the word `undefined`

Comment: Can you try  `public JsonResult IsAvailableUN(string Username){return new JsonResult { Data = !Conn.Accounts.Any(Accounts => Accounts.Username == Username), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};}`

Answer (score 0):

Your method should have same parameter like the property which have Remote validation .

Check your property name .It should be

```
[Remote("IsAvailableUN", "Account", ErrorMessage = "This username is already taken!")]
public string Username{get;set;} //Same as function parameter
```

And return should be anonymous type .Not plain true /false

```
var anonymous =new {
  result=true;
};

return Json(anonymous , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the response. My method has exactly the same name as my validation.

Answer (score 0):

!Conn.Accounts.Any(Accounts => Accounts.Username == Username) will return boolean (not object).

It should be json object { "propertyName" : "value" }. In your case it should be

```
 { "propertyName" : true }
```

or

```
{ "propertyName" : false}
```

You can use

```
 var isValid = !Conn.Accounts.Any(Accounts => Accounts.Username == Username);
 return Json(new { Valid = isValid }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply to my post. Unfortunately this solution didn't work either (same result)

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult IsAvailableUN(string Username)
{
 var isExistUser = !Conn.Accounts.Any(Accounts => Accounts.Username == Username);
 return Json(new { Result =isExistUser},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

try like this.it should be work.you should return data as JSON object not as boolean variable